# Responsive divs won't scale

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I have two divs next to each other which have the class `.category` and they are supposed to be responsive.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="category">
        <img src="images/category1.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor.
        </p>
    </div
    <div class="category">
        <img src="images/category2.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.category {
    max-width: 470px;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
```

When I start resizing the window, the second `.category` block moves underneath the first `.category` block. However, I want both the `.category` blocks to reduce in width and stay next to each other.

Anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have some typographic errors in your HTML Markup (you are missing the `>` sign on the closing div tag of the first category div).

Second, you should be using percentage widths for responsive elements like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/CW2zb/)**

CSS :

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.category {
    max-width:470px;
    width: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    float:left;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This indeed works, thank you. A question about this though: I want my divs to be exactly 470px wide at its max, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @2339870 of course, add `max-width:470px;` check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/CW2zb/

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left;` to .category in css and use either `%` or a css media query

```
@media(min-width:something;){
   .category {
      width: something;
   }
}
```

to set the width of the elements.